# Отправка аудио-файла из Angular в Php

Tags: typescript, fileupload, angular4, formdata

Здравствуйте, я делаю сервис с возможностью заливать собственные аудио-файлы, где front-end часть на **Angular 4**, а back-end на **PHP (Laravel 5)**. Сейчас проблема с отправкой самого файла. Увидел способ отправлять файлы с помощью **FormData**, но когда добавляю файл в объект FormData (`formData.append('fileName', file)`) и потом вывожу в его в консоль, то обнаруживаю его пустым.

[image: Angular код]

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь. Если у вас есть другие идеи для отправки и хранения аудио-файлов, пожалуйста просветлите меня.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось проблема на backend стороне, поэтому **php** тоже возвращает пустое значение. А на скрине выше я неправильно проверял есть ли файл в **FormData**. Невозможно достать данные из **FormData** через `console.log(formData)`, для этого существует специальный метод `formData.get('key')` или `formData.getAll()` (чтобы достать все данные).